# Why swift view does not update with UIKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, tabbar

I have swiftUI tabbar with animation also I have UITabbarViewController which contains this swiftUI view.

SwiftUI

```
struct MainTabBarView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MainTabBarViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            TabItem(currentIndex: $viewModel.index, tabIndex: 0, tab: .home)
            Spacer()
            TabItem(currentIndex: $viewModel.index, tabIndex: 1, tab: .search)
            Spacer()
            TabItem(currentIndex: $viewModel.index, tabIndex: 2, tab: .library)
        }.padding(.top, 8).padding(.leading, 28).padding(.trailing, 28)
        .padding(.bottom, 8)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.2))

}
```

UITabbarViewController:

```
final class MainTabBarViewController: UITabBarController, Navigatable {
         private var viewModel = MainTabBarViewModel()

        // MARK: - Lifecycle
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            bindViewModel()
        }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configTabBarView()
    }
 
     
        private func configTabBarView() {
            let view = UIHostingController(rootView: MainTabBarView(viewModel: viewModel))
            addChild(child)
            tabBar.addSubview(view.view)
            view.didMove(toParent: self)
            tabBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")
            view.view.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.leading.trailing.top.equalToSuperview()
                make.height.equalTo(100)
            }
         
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
final class MainTabBarViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
   
   @Published var index: Int = 0 
}
```

This is the code of my custom view with tabs.
When I press on tab -> index from viewModel is changing in this view and then

```
struct TabItem: View {
    
    @Binding var currentIndex: Int
    var tabIndex: Int
    var isCurrentTab: Bool {
        return currentIndex == tabIndex
    }
    
    var tab: Tabs
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(uiImage: tab.icon).resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .foregroundColor(isCurrentTab ? R.color.primaryColor()!.swiftUI : R.color.grayScaleDark()!.swiftUI)
            Text(isCurrentTab ? tab.title : "").font(Font(R.font.poppinsRegular(size: 16)! as CTFont))
                .foregroundColor(isCurrentTab ? R.color.primaryColor()!.swiftUI : R.color.grayScaleDark()!.swiftUI)
        }.padding(15)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.currentIndex = tabIndex
           logWarn(String(tabIndex))
        }
        .background(self.tabIndex == currentIndex ? Color(R.color.pink()!) : Color.white)
        .frame(height: 44.0)
        .cornerRadius(22.0)
        .clipped()
    }
    
}
```

The problems that index is changing, but tab does not update view. It is look, like view does not update.

Comment: You're missing a lot of required code for someone to be able to test this out

Comment: I was just thinking that I'm not familiar with `TabItem`.   I am familiar with `TabView`. Unless `TabItem` is a new addition to SwiftUI and just missed it (I just searched to check and came up empty handed), I think seeing it's definition is important.

Comment: @ChipJarred it is my own view. I added this code. Look above

Comment: Maybe I'm having a refresh problem, but it looks like the same code.  Did you add a code snippet for how `TabItem` is defined?

Comment: @ChipJarred I added code with my tab ) Could you please look one more time

Comment: Now it's showing up.  Maybe Safari somehow cached part of the page before.

Comment: One issue is that it shouldn't compile as given, because you a duplicate override of `viewDidLoad` in `MainTabBarViewController`.  That's not the issue you describe, but it is a problem.

Comment: I change  ObservedObject var viewModel: MainTabBarViewModel to State var index, and pass viewModel.index and it helped

Comment: Yes that would do it.  I assumed that `MainTabBarViewModel` existed so that you can add other things to the view model later and keep them in one place.  Another solution would be to pass `MainTabBarViewModel` to `TabItem` with a KeyPath to `.index`.   The problem is that your `TabItem` writes to the current index `onTapGesture`, and the compiler won't let you do that through the KeyPath even though `MainTabViewModel` is a class, because `TabItem` is immutable in that context.

Comment: The question should include a [mre]. Even with the edits, there's not enough code to really diagnose what's going on. For example, `bindViewModel` is probably pretty important to what's going on, but the code isn't included.

Comment: You aren’t listening to the  viewModel. You have to use Combine, anyCancellable and sink. Something like anyCancellable = viewModel.sink..... in your ViewController. I don’t have my Mac right now so I can’t write something specific but you should be able to find other questions if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it would be helpful for the given code to compile, I think I've pieced together a solution that allows the current index to remain in `MainTabBarViewModel`, under the assumption that the it is intended to hold other things in the future.  I also make the assumption that `TabItem` is supposed to be sufficiently generic that it doesn't have to depend on `MainTabVarViewModel` specifically.

My idea is based on providing a key path to the current index when creating the `TabItem`.   Were it not for the fact that `TabItem` updates the current index that would be simple enough.  However, because it does update it, in a `onTapGesture` closure, the compiler complains that it can't write through the KeyPath, because `self` is immutable.  So... summoning the ghost a David Wheeler, I tried doing it through a closure saved in `TabItem.init`... which doesn't exist, so adding that is part of the solution.

First `TabItem` becomes a generic:

```swift
struct TabItem<TabBarViewModel: ObservableObject>: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TabBarViewModel
    let indexKeyPath: WritableKeyPath<TabBarViewModel, Int>
    let tapClosure: (Int) -> Void
    // @Binding var currentIndex: Int
    var currentIndex: Int { viewModel[keyPath: indexKeyPath] }

    ...

    init(currentIndexIn viewModel: TabBarViewModel, at indexKeyPath: WritableKeyPath<TabBarViewModel, Int>, tabIndex: Int, tab: Tabs)
    {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.indexKeyPath = indexKeyPath
        self.tabIndex = tabIndex
        self.tab = tab
        self.tapClosure = { self.viewModel[keyPath: indexKeyPath] = $0 }
    }
```

With that everything in `TabItem` compiles (after removing references to unprovided code) except for this bit in `body`

```swift
        .onTapGesture {
           currentIndex = tabIndex
           print(String(tabIndex))
        }
```

I change that to use the closure that was saved off in the `init`:

```swift
        .onTapGesture {
           tapClosure(tabIndex)
           print(String(tabIndex))
        }
```

Then in `MainTabBarView`'s `body` creating a `TabItem` changes *from* this:

```swift
TabItem(currentIndex: $viewModel.index, tabIndex: 0, tab: .home)
```

*to* this

```swift
TabItem(currentIndexIn: viewModel, at: \.index, tabIndex: 0, tab: .home)
```

Since there is too much code missing for me to compile and test it, this is a bit of a guess.  I stubbed out missing code just to silence the errors for it, so I can say that at least this solution compiles.  It would need to be applied and tested in the actual app to verify whether it works.

Anyway, assuming it does work, this solution still allows keeping the index in an observable object without relying on the particular type of that object.